# How to display Material-ui Alert based on the response of axios.post reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Currently, using default alert which is  `alert(response.data.result)`. To make my site more beautiful, I want to use Material-ui Alert. https://material-ui.com/components/alert/

My issue is I have no idea on how to call it from `const`.

Here's my code.

```
function Test(){
const saveData=async() => {
    await axios.post('/API', passedParams)
    .then(response => {
      if(response.data.success === true)
        {
          alert(response.data.result)
        }
      else
        {
          alert(response.data.result)
          //<Alert severity='error'>{response.data.result}</Alert> tried to use this but nothing displayed
          }
     }).catch(error=>{
        alert(error)
     })

//content of modal
cosnt bodyInsert = (
<div>
    ...fields
    <Button onClick={()=>saveData()}>Save</Button>
</div>
)
return(
<div>
<Modal
   open = {modalInsert}
   onClose = {openCloseModalInsert}>
   {bodyInsert}
</Modal>
</div>
)
}
export default Test;
```

Hoping for your consideration. thank you.

Comment: You should add your current <Alert /> component into your rendered component and use state to show or hide it. And you can only control this state into true or false to show or hide that component. If you post your full code, then I can help you with code.

Comment: Hi @ArtemMedianyk I updated my posted code. Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
function Test(){
const saveData=async() => {
    const [alert, setAlert] = useState(false);
    const [alertContent, setAlertContent] = useState('');
    await axios.post('/API', passedParams)
    .then(response => {
      if(response.data.success === true)
        {
          setAlertContent(response.data.result);
          setAlert(true);
        }
      else
        {
          setAlertContent(response.data.result);
          setAlert(true);
        }
     }).catch(error=>{
        alert(error)
     })

//content of modal
cosnt bodyInsert = (
<div>
    ...fields
    <Button onClick={()=>saveData()}>Save</Button>
</div>
)
return(
<div>
{alert ? <Alert severity='error'>{alertContent}</Alert> : <></> }
<Modal
   open = {modalInsert}
   onClose = {openCloseModalInsert}>
   {bodyInsert}
</Modal>
</div>
)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Artem, thank you! it is now working. I just put the const for alert outside the save function since `alertContent` is undefined inside `return()`. Is there a way to put it over the displayed modal? As of now it displayed beyond the modal specially if error alert. Thank you

Comment: You will have to pass alertContent to your Modal using props and state.

Comment: typo - const not cosnt

Answer (score 2):

I think you can not do it that way. Use a state for it.

```
const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(null);

const saveData=async() => {
    await axios.post('/API', passedParams)
    .then(response => {
      if(response.data.success === true)
        {
          alert(response.data.result)
        }
      else
        {
          alert(response.data.result)
          setShowAlert(response.data.result);
        }
         
     }).catch(error=>{
        alert(error)
     })

// Your return
return showAlert && <Alert severity='error'  onClose={() => setShowAlert(null)} > { showAlert } </Alert>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collapse` component [collapse doc](https://mui.com/components/transitions/)

```
const alertComponent = (<Alert severity='error'>{alertContent}</Alert>);

<Collapse in={alert}>{ alertComponent }</Collapse>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `<Alert>` and `<Dialog>` components to create an alert in the react application

**Example:**

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import Alert from '@material-ui/lab/Alert'
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton'
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close'
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog'


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        '& > * + *': {
            marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
        },
        width: '100%',
    },
}))

export default function TransitionAlerts(props) {
    const classes = useStyles()
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Dialog open={props.open}>
                <Alert
                    action={
                        <IconButton
                            aria-label='close'
                            color='inherit'
                            size='small'
                            onClick={
                              useCallback(() => props.closeAlert({msg: '', open: false }))
                            }
                        >
                            <CloseIcon fontSize='inherit' />
                        </IconButton>
                    }
                >
                    {props.msg}
                </Alert>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    )
}
```